# Stranded Asteroid habitats are raided by solar sailed viking longboats

Tags: space

*1st idea posted, please be gentle...

Is it plausible to use solar sails with the radiation from a gas giant to raid asteroid clusters internally terraformed, and would tacking be a real consideration

Comment: um... welcome to the site and all that,  you may want to edit your Question to add... a LOT more detail. like space longboats, are they actual longboats that are open topped and the passengers are just hanging in open space? you mean viking like or are they actual Norseman devil in the details

Comment: I'd suggest doing basic research on solar sails, but note the word "solar" - i.e. needs light from a star, not radiation from a planet.

Comment: Please add more details. Under some conditions, using lightsails might be a good thing, under other conditions it would be impossible. Tell us your starting conditions.

Comment: The thought started out as , What would happen to the People left behind in an emergency evacuation of clusters of asteroids parked in some semblance of a stable orbit around a inhospitable planet. If they were housing and light industrial units the people would the ability to manufacture anything that did not include dense or rare materials.

Comment: oh and asto the Viking thing. People will take what they cant get any easier so some asteroids chose to raid and scavenge. think storage tanks with simple jets for alignment , i have no idea about solar sails thought maybe the material used would react to radiation not just ?photons?..

Comment: also if you want to talk to someone other then the group use @ then there names like this @Tim Ellis helps a lot when your trying to talk to just one person

Comment: So with abit of googling let me modify this thought, with a modified Nuclear pulse drive to accelerate these raiders ship, is it plausible for ppl to transit between these moons with conventional explosives as the "fuel" for shuttles modified with push plates . OR would it be better for them to use the gases from cracking rock to power their shuttles

Answer (score 3):

With some tinkering, this might be workable.

Solar sails might be a bit impractical for a raiding ship, **unless** they were just using them to reach the relevant solar system. Once they get a couple light-minutes away, they stow the sails and switch to thrusters. Or, if your okay with keeping the viking motif but getting rid of the solar sails, turn them into solar panels. Its pretty low tech for space-vikings, but this seems like a scavengers-verses-Robinson_Crusoe situation, so this might be plausible.

Something you may have fun with some of [worldbuilding's discussions on space boarding parties](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=boarding). Among the possible weapons suggested for boarding a ship/space station (without venting out all the air via gunshot holes or wreking the goods the raiders wanted in the first place) are shields and melee weapons. Now you have a justification why your raiders are armed like 10th century Norsemen!

I might suggest against making the space-longboats open top, but I'm sure you could justify that as **really** good and comfy space-suits and the need to get out of their ship on onto the hull of the others as fast as possible. Still, an almond-shaped craft with solar sails (or solar panels) would probably look enough like a longboat for readers/viewers to get the allusion.

A possible problem could be that its incredibly easy to shoot down invading spacecraft in . . . uh . . . space. Just a bloke with a quality telescope and a 50 caliber sniper rifle might be able to fend off your viking raiders. An easy fix would be putting a big object (like a thick metal sheet or a rock) in front of the ships to act like a shield. [A laser array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Weapon_System) would be preferable, but that a hard thing to make without some fancy computers, factories, and know-how.

Lastly, asteroids around a gas giant would technically be called moons. Asteroid belts circle around the sun between the gas giants and the rocky planets near the core. The moons around a gas giant do contain sweet stuff like water, but asteroid belts have valuable metals that are a lot easier to get to. Either one would make for a good setting for this story, I just thought you might benefit from some terminology.

Welcome to Worldbuilding, by the way. I sincerely hope you have a enjoyable time looking about for answers and questions.

Comment: Btw thank you all for the feed back.

Answer (score 0):

1)  Planets don't emit enough radiation to meaningfully propel a solar sail.  There's a reason it's called a **solar** sail--it needs that kind of power.

2)  Anything as low-tech as a Viking longboat has no hope of providing enough life support for such a trip.  Your voyage is going to be measured in months **at a minimum**.

3)  It's not going to work.  Solar sails are very big, very delicate (tissue paper is incredibly tough in comparison) obvious and very slow.  The proverbial sitting duck isn't remotely an easy a target.